# decode XML with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

When trying to read the file here nothing is returned...

What am I doing wrong?

## beginning of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:ns7="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SpecializedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"><cec:UBLExtensions xmlns:cec="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"><cec:UBLExtension><cec:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:profile:dsig:signature</cec:ExtensionURI><cec:ExtensionContent><sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"><sig:SignatureInformation><cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signatures:1</cbc:ID><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"><XPath>count(ancestor-or-self::sig:UBLDocumentSignatures | here()/ancestor::sig:UBLDocumentSignatures[1]) &gt; count(ancestor-or-self::sig:UBLDocumentSignatures)</XPath></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>Agc2+1rOPYaPgixs6RTiLZzoj4H5/96eA8nv6dlU6yA=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Mp3ziREgnkg0jU+l+Jl+4viQKFTwMnY7DTFlK1jzbVZjV7r9nmnePSrr/nvdJWZt1bheKMiEMYBi
ax7bcGUZYj4QFdO7z8W+MvsxGGG0TswRBay51J+ja08rtob/YQ5Z+Yc25PEko3nuePItYPVAKsXW
E51EAWgVd/kXpRF6xrQ=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>qjPnoh/BgvN22UWUVcwVYr9xWj49ffp2obvmR5WttIJssS5ZbCYOxjIjO3gIcNAu6NLFn5gpsp95
FPNY1JDGII1qPnp9zyI6HKyA3yb5Vq9ONm2cLRfOz2zrvPdG+38ZLMzHe1rLALXEoIqfJWWt3u2B
UvWP+h5ZYzm8px1gmJM=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIICATCCAWoCCQCo1AOqHHrvcDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBFMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTETMBEGA1UE
CBMKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UEChMYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMB4XDTEwMDQw
OTA5MTkyN1oXDTI5MTIyNTA5MTkyN1owRTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxEzARBgNVBAgTClNvbWUtU3Rh
dGUxITAfBgNVBAoTGEludGVybmV0IFdpZGdpdHMgUHR5IEx0ZDCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOB
jQAwgYkCgYEAqjPnoh/BgvN22UWUVcwVYr9xWj49ffp2obvmR5WttIJssS5ZbCYOxjIjO3gIcNAu
6NLFn5gpsp95FPNY1JDGII1qPnp9zyI6HKyA3yb5Vq9ONm2cLRfOz2zrvPdG+38ZLMzHe1rLALXE
oIqfJWWt3u2BUvWP+h5ZYzm8px1gmJMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQARLOs0egYgj7q7
mN0uthdbzAEg75Ssgh4JuOJ3iXI/sbqAIQ9uwsLodo+Fkpb5AiLlNFu7mCZXG/SzAAO3ZBLAWy4S
KsXANu2/s6U5ClYd93HoZwzXobKb+2+aMf7KiAg1wHPUcyKx2c5nplgqQ7Hwldk9S9yzaRsYEGWT
+xpSUA==</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></sig:SignatureInformation></sig:UBLDocumentSignatures></cec:ExtensionContent></cec:UBLExtension></cec:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>OIOUBL-2.01</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID schemeAgencyID="320" schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:profileid-1.2">urn:www.nesubl.eu:profiles:profile5:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>10</cbc:ID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2011-11-15</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="320" listID="urn:oioubl:codelist:invoicetypecode-1.1">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
```

## code

```
$file = 'tradeshift_invoice.xml';
if(is_file($file)){
    echo 'file exists<br><br>';
}
else{
    echo 'file does not exists<br><br>';
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

//$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(simplexml_load_file($file), 0, true);

echo 'count '.$xml->count().'<br><br>';

foreach($xml->children() as $child){
    print_r($child);
}
```

## output

```
file exists

count 0
```

Comment: I think you forgot `</Invoice>`!

Answer (score 0):

new SimpleXMLElement is only for string data, not for a file. You want to use:

```
simplexml_load_file($file)
```

instead...

Look for it under: http://www.php.net/manual/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: this is returned... object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }

Comment: I really don't get this, you sure your XML file is valid at this point? Contains the XML header and is validly structured? ... :S The doc is clear, there should be data or it should be FALSE, so i'm thinking your object is simply empty because there is no data to read :(

Comment: hmmm.. Im quite sure that its a valid xml file.. has updated my question again with the beginning of the xml file :)

Comment: simplexml doesn't support xml namespaces. Your first node has "cec:UBLExtensions". So it'll never work. You need to use a more complex XML parser. I only use simplexml, so i can't help you more.

Comment: Have you a root element ? (if it is <Invoice>, make sure you closed it)